# Kendo UI Chart Tooltip default to zero if no data

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, user-interface, kendo-ui

I am fixing a "bug" for a tooltip in a Kendo UI chart. The bug is if I am showing data for a current fiscal quarter which goes through end of September and I hover over a datapoint after current date, it does show the date and where it would also show currency (ex. $0.48), it just shows "$". I need this to default to "$0.00" if it has no data. My current tooltip template is as follows:
                            .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
                                .Template(string.Format(format, "#=value#") + "#= kendo.format('{0: (M/dd/yyyy)}',category) #")
                                .Visible(true)
                            );

Can anyone offer suggestions on resolving this? Have googled to no avail. Thanks much!

Comment: Anyone able to input on this?

Comment: Did you solved this? I'm having a similar problem...